# How to access the root folder in react/next

Tags: reactjs, frontend, next.js

is it possible to refer to the root folder of the project in react? In Vue I could do it via @. For example '@/components/UI/Button'. Can I do the same in React/Next?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a file `jsconfig.json` at root of your project and add this code to it:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "@/components/*": ["components/*"]
    }
  }
}
```

If your project structure is like `./src/components/UI/Button.jsx`, then change `["components/*"]` to `["src/components/*"]` in the above config.

Comment: I did as you said, IDE sees the component and shows its props, but in console I have a error "Can't resolve module (not found) in React.js". Do you know what could be the problem?

Comment: @DeeEss which Next.js version are you using? To use this feature you should be using v9.4 or above.

Comment: Next.js is v10.2.3

Comment: @DeeEss See this sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/kind-violet-yqb25 It is working fine there. You probably need to re-run `yarn dev`/`npm run dev`.

Comment: if there is Typescript then you should change tsconfig.json the same way.

Answer (score 1):

I am gonna explain with one of my working project.

First, create a file jsconfig.json at root directory of your project.

[image]

Second, add this code to it like this.

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "baseUrl": ".",
        "paths": {
            "@Components/*": [
                "components/*"
            ],
            "@services/*": [
                "services/*"
            ],
            "@Models/*": [
                "Models/*"
            ],
            "@lib/*": [
                "lib/*"
            ],
            "@utils/*": [
                "utils/*"
            ],
            "@Context/*": [
                "Context/*"
            ],
            "@public/*": [
                "public/*"
            ],
            "@styles/*": [
                "styles/*"
            ],
            "@modules/*": [
                "modules/*"
            ],
        }
    },
    "include": [
        "."
    ]
}
```

Third, you can refer these location in your code like this (Eg: /components/PaymentPanel.jsx").

```
...
import MyFormHelperText from @Components/common/MyFormHelperText';
import DeleteIcon from '@public/images/svg/trash.svg';
import {proceedVerify} from '@lib/authAPI';
import {UserContext} from '@Context/User/UserProvider';
import Sports from '@modules/Sports';
import {
  sendNotify,
} from "@services/promotion/promotionService";
```

And please refer next.js and react versions in package.json.

```
{
  "dependencies": {
        ...
        "next": "^11.1.3",
        "next-auth": "^3.29.3",
        "react": "^17.0.2",
        ...
  }
}
```